# Edit Text Focus Change Listener

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus

I have two Edit text in an item of Recycler view, I have set a focus change listener for each of edit texts. The input type of both is text. Focus change listener works well for the first Edit text, but for the second one even I click the check button(right bottom) from keyboard it does not lose focus. What could be the problem ?

```
holder.textView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
                //textView.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                if(b){
                    holder.textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.TabYellow));
                    discreteScrollView.scrollToPosition(infiniteAdapter.getClosestPosition(position));
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Input loose focus",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
                    holder.textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                    //  textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                }
            }
        });
        holder.newToDo.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
                if(b){
                    discreteScrollView.scrollToPosition(infiniteAdapter.getClosestPosition(position));
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Input loose focus",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
                }
            }
        });`
```

Comment: we can not guess the problem without any code. And for a suggestion having `EditText` as a list item is not a good practice you better come up with with some different design approach .

Comment: I have added code, why it is not a good practice or what is better ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do not use editText inside recycler or listview like views.

Comment: @ShaluTD so what is an alternative solution for that, or why I should not use it in recycler or listview ?

Comment: Because `EditText`  takes input from keyboard  and during scroll of list you need to preserve the state for each edittext .Which is quite a hectic.This is why you do not see this type of design usually. You can take input with a `Dialog` on click.

Comment: Okey, I got it thank you.

Comment: @ADM by the way, do you have any idea about why the second input does not lose focus ?

Answer (score 0):

Although It's not a good approach to create such type of layout but still what you can do is add keyEventListner of keyboard and check the type of key and insert the code of passing focus to another position's edit text.

Comment: When second Edit text focused, if I click the first Edit text the second one loses focus, but it does not lose focus, what is reason for that ?